# Concatenate character to a sentence c

Tags: c, concatenation, string-concatenation, sentence

How do you add a char to a sentence.

For example I have a player1 and would like to add the player1 to the beginning of the sentence " please enter how many times you would like to shuffle the deck.

I'm used to java where you can just add the + to it to concatenate the variable and string(s)

I have this so far but it doesn't like any of what I have typed:

```
printf(&player1 + " please enter how many times you would like to shuffle the deck: ");
int numShuf;
scanf("%i", &numShuf);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
printf("%s please enter how many times you would like to shuffle the deck: ", player1);
```

`printf` means print formatted, so you can format what you want to print and add the variables in as arguments.

Comment: @kevorski what do you mean by putting it on one line?

Comment: @austin when i print it i get this `kevin
, please enter how many times you would like to shuffle the deck: ` it prints on two separate lines

Comment: @kevorski: the only place there can be a line break is after `kevin`, and the line break would appear there because you didn't delete the newline after `kevin`'s name when you read it in.